# Find duplicate columns in 30M record table

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates

The subject table has 30M rows. I am executing a query to find the duplicate `hash`. `hash` is defined as

```
 `hash` varchar(50) NOT NULL;
```

The query is

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   (SELECT Count(id) `num`,
               `signature`
        FROM   `images`
        WHERE  `hash` IS NOT NULL
        GROUP  BY `hash`
        HAVING `num` > 1) AS `count_table`
```

It takes about 5-7 minutes before I pressed `Ctrl+C` to abort the query. I run it again and still couldn't wait that much time.

How can i get this result faster?

I know this will be a little bit slow while doing the group by. But8 mins is too much I think.

Comment: Do you have an index on `hash` or... er.. `signature`?

Comment: Please, post your table's structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is an index on `hash`(or is it `signature`?).

Replace `COUNT(id)` with `COUNT(hash)` (or `COUNT(signature)`).

Comment: it does not have a index. I have applied index and its much faster now.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the count of duplicate entries then you could try

```
select count(*)-count(distinct hash) from images
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you only want columns returned which are duplicated?
try this
SELECT * FROM table_name AS t1 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM table_name AS t2 WHERE t1.hash=t2.hash and t1.id!=t2.id);